# Send LocalStorage in ahref using php

Tags: javascript, php

I am a looking for a way to set LocalStorage in A Href.

Here is the PHP code:

```
 <table cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>View</th>
         <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>

        <?php
        $count=1;
        $sel_query="Select * from userdetails ORDER BY id desc;";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
                  //something has to be done later.
        ?>

      <tr>
         <td align="center"><?php echo $count; ?>
         <td align="center"><?php echo $row["docname"]; ?>
         <td align="center"><a href="view.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">View</a></td>
         <td align="center"><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">Edit</a></td>
      </tr>

      <?php $count++; } ?>

     </table>
```

On click of edit or view, I want to store "$row["id"];" to local storage? I need this in local storage because I am using js library which is looking for localstorage[key].

Is this possible if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to make javascript redirects the user. So you can assign an onClick eventHandler to each `a` element.
And the handler function would be something like this

```
function handleLinkClick (e) {
e.preventDefault (); 
//so we can do stuff before the user leaves the page
 const id = e.target.href.split ("?").pop ();
//just extracting the id
 localStorage.setItem ("myKey", id);
window.location.href = e.target.href;
}
```

Comment: Sorry! I am totally new to php and js. Can you please explain? const id = e.target.href.split ("?").pop (); and e.target.href? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah sure, it simply takes the href attribute string, splits it into an array using the delimeter "?" and pop returns the last element in such array. As for e.target it points to your a element while .href returns the href attribute

Comment: what if I don't have a href without ? How do I address that? Is it possible in my case?

Comment: One way I can think of it is to write the value from PHP into the JavaScript function but that will be bad for readability I guess.